# How to connect a SATA / ESATA / USB 3.0 device over Gigabit Ethernet

Tags: usb, sata, gigabit-ethernet, esata

I am looking for a way to connect an 5.25 SATA removable drive bay from [CRU](http://www.cru-inc.com/products/dataport/dp10_sassata_6g/) to our HP Proliant 360 blade server. Unfortunately the server has no support for USB 3.0 and no free PCI slot to upgrade USB 3.0 functionality. Also it doesn't have an eSATA port. Is there a solution to connect this drive bay via Ethernet? The key is the reading speed as we use the CRU drives to receive big file sets.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm confused. The specs on that list it as having a SAS/SATA connector. Why are you talking about USB and Ethernet?

Comment: We have an external case that it fitts into with USB3 and SATA. I mention ethernet because that is the only way I see to connect it to the HP server in a somewhat fast way.

Answer (score 1):

Current USB over IP implementations supports only USB 2.0 speed, and in my opinion isn't very fast and reliable.

If you need a robust way to connect HDDs over network, you should look for some [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network) (provides block storage)/[NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) instead (provides network filesystem), depending on your needs. Most SAN and NAS hardware comes with hot-swap bays.

Comment: I looked into the NAS option. The problem is that I can not use the hotswap bays of the NAS since I am tied to the CRU drive enclosure. Some NAS have a eSata and USB3 port for an external drive, but I am not sure if the speed from these ports will be anywhere close to the internal SATA connection.

Comment: Other option I can propose is to install CRU enclosure internally in some of your workstations, and configure it as iSCSI target for the server, which would be an initiator. Probably this option requires you to restrict physical access to workstation for untrusted employees and configure dedicated VLAN for iSCSI with MTU > 8KiB. Edit: typos.

Comment: I think that is the most feasible option for us.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with ethernet. Your HP ProLiant DL360 is NOT a blade server either. DO you know the *generation* of your DL360 server? Is it a G5, G6, G7 or *Gen8*?

Most of that product line has two PCIe slots. That's your expansion option for the platform. If you don't have any free PCIe slots, then you don't have any options to accommodate this external drive.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was a blade. It is a Gen8 and both PCI slots are taken up for A 10GBethernet and FC Card to connect to a HP MSA. Guess I am out of luck then and need a dedicated machine just for the CRU drive bay.

Comment: Just use the onboard ports as USB 2.0.

Comment: That is too time consuming for 1-2TB of data transfer.

Comment: At least you'll get some sort of transfer. Right now, you don't have _anything_.